# CSS - Trouble in positioning content in ::after

Tags: html, css, alignment, contenteditable, pseudo-element

Sorry for my bad CSS skills.

**Problem:** I want to add a positive and negative symbol to all elements of a `<ol>` using CSS (no images!).

#### First Attempt

My solution was to put an empty `<span>` in the beginning of all `<li>` with a "positive" or "negative" class that has the corresponding CSS to create a positive or negative symbol. The problem is that the `<ol>` must be `contenteditable="true"`, that means that when someone adds another line (`<li>`) to the `<ol>`, it will *not* come with the `<span>` that creates the symbol with the class "positive" and with the `content: "+";` rule in the pseudo-element `positive::after`. In sum: when adding a new line, it won't come with a positive symbol.

This can be seen in the following code:

```css
.positive {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-right: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  color: green;
}

.positive:after {
  content: "+";
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
}

.negative {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.negative:after {
  content: "−";
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
}

ol {
  padding-left: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<ol contenteditable="true">
  <li><span class="positive"></span>1st positive</li>
  <li><span class="positive"></span>2nd positive</li>
  <li><span class="positive"></span>3rd positive</li>
  <li><span class="positive"></span>4th positive, please add more below! contenteditable="true"</li>
</ol>
<ol contenteditable="true">
  <li><span class="negative"></span>1st negative</li>
  <li><span class="negative"></span>2nd negative</li>
  <li><span class="negative"></span>3rd negative</li>
  <li><span class="negative"></span>4th negative, please add more below! contenteditable="true"</li>
</ol>
```

#### Second Attempt

So I thought I'd get rid of the `<span>` and directly insert all CSS in a `li.positive::before`. This, indeed, makes all new `<li>`s have prefixed a positive or negative symbol, just like I wanted. But now the `"+"` and `"-"` `content` is misaligned in relation to the circle of the positive or negative symbol.

This can be seen in the following code:

```css
.positive:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-right: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  color: green;
  content: "+";
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}

.negative:before {
  //border-radius: 50%; 
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  content: "−";
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}

ol {
  padding-left: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<ol contenteditable="true">
  <li class="positive">1st positive</li>
  <li class="positive">2nd positive</li>
  <li class="positive">3rd positive</li>
  <li class="positive">4th positive, please add more below! contenteditable="true"</li>
</ol>
<ol contenteditable="true">
  <li class="negative">1st negative</li>
  <li class="negative">2nd negative</li>
  <li class="negative">3rd negative</li>
  <li class="negative">4th negative, please add more below! contenteditable="true"</li>
</ol>
```

### Final Question

How can I put all CSS in the `::before` pseudo-element (just like in my Second Attempt, above) but align the "+" and "-" in the symbols so to put them in the middle of the white circle that surrounds them?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `justify-content: center` to pseudo element (as you already made them `display: inline-flex`).

You may also adjust the `line-height` to fix vertical alignment.

```css
.positive:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-right: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  color: green;
  content: "+";
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height:16px;
}

.negative:before {
  //border-radius: 50%; 
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  content: "−";
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height:16px;
}

ol {
  padding-left: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<ol contenteditable="true">
  <li class="positive">1st positive</li>
  <li class="positive">2nd positive</li>
  <li class="positive">3rd positive</li>
  <li class="positive">4th positive, please add more below! contenteditable="true"</li>
</ol>
<ol contenteditable="true">
  <li class="negative">1st negative</li>
  <li class="negative">2nd negative</li>
  <li class="negative">3rd negative</li>
  <li class="negative">4th negative, please add more below! contenteditable="true"</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Brilliant!!! Thank you so much! I spent hours searching for this. Still, the "+" and "-" seem a little misaligned vertically, do you know if it's possible to put them a little upwards?

Comment: @flen you may adjust this using `line-height` .. try `line-height: 16px;`

Answer (score 1):

## 3 Ways to Create an Ordered List with Font Icons

Using so many alignments seems fragile. As an alternative, you could use font icons instead.

**Pseudo-class Font**

**Demo 1**

Use **[`\2295`](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/circled%20plus)** and **[`\229f`](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/squared%20minus)** albeit they are not as well polished as OP's but they are one piece.

```css
li {
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin: 1.2ex 0;
}

.positive:before {
  content: '\2295\a0';
  color: green;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  display: inline
}

.negative:before {
  content: '\229f\a0';
  color: tomato;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  display: inline
}

ol {
  padding-left: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<ol contenteditable="true">
  <li class="positive">1st positive</li>
  <li class="positive">2nd positive</li>
  <li class="positive">3rd positive</li>
  <li class="positive">4th positive, please add more below! contenteditable="true"</li>
</ol>
<ol contenteditable="true">
  <li class="negative">1st negative</li>
  <li class="negative">2nd negative</li>
  <li class="negative">3rd negative</li>
  <li class="negative">4th negative, please add more below! contenteditable="true"</li>
</ol>
```

---

**Pseudo-class Font Awesome**

**Demo 2**

If appearance is the main concern, take it to the next level with [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/examples/) (see Demo 2) and use their icons by pseudo-class. Use this [site for reference](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/). One problem is that they do not have a line circle with plus icon, but strangely enough they do have a line square with plus, a filled square with plus, and a filled circle with plus.

```css
li {
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin: 1.2ex 0;
}

.positive:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f196\a0';
  color: green;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  display: inline
}

.negative:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f147\a0';
  color: tomato;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  display: inline
}

.positive.inv::before {
  content: '\f0fe\a0';
}

.negative.inv::before {
  content: '\f146\a0';
}

.positive.orb::before {
  content: '\f055\a0';
}

.negative.orb::before {
  content: '\f056\a0';
}

ol 
  padding-left: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-plus-circle"></i>can be used</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-minus-circle"></i>can be used</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-plus-square"></i>as bullets</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-minus-square"></i>in lists</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-plus-circle-o"></i>can be used</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-minus-circle-o"></i>can be used</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>as bullets</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-minus-square-o"></i>in lists</li>
</ul>

<ol contenteditable="true">
  <li class="positive orb">1st positive</li>
  <li class="positive inv">2nd positive</li>
  <li class="positive">3rd positive</li>
</ol>
<ol contenteditable="true">
  <li class="negative orb">1st negative</li>
  <li class="negative inv">2nd negative</li>
  <li class="negative">3rd negative</li>
</ol>
```

---

**Font Awesome Standard with CSS Counters**

**Demo 3**

There's also the standard method using `.fa-*` classes. with the use of CSS `counters` to compensate for the [lack of an `<ol>` alternative](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#list) (see Demo3).

```css
.fa-ul {
  counter-reset: fa;
  line-height: 1.3
}

.fa-ul li {
  counter-increment: fa;
  position: relative
}

.fa-ul li::before {
  content: counter(fa)'.\a0';
  position: absolute;
  left: -4.5ch
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-plus-circle"></i>fa-plus-circle</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-minus-circle"></i>fa-minus-circle</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-plus-square"></i>fa-plus-square</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-minus-square"></i>fa-minus-square</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-plus-circle-o">?</i>fa-plus-circle-o</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-minus-circle-o">?</i>fa-minus-circle-o</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>fa-plus-square-o</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-minus-square-o"></i>fa-minus-square-o</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Amazing answer! And I didn't know amp-what.com , thank you so much for sharing! &#9786; It would indeed have saved me time and trouble...

Comment: You are welcome. If you want only the pictographs, this [site](https://coolsymbol.com) has them all. BTW `&#****;` is the format to use in HTML. `\****` is for CSS content, and `\u****` is for JS